# Why does the order of columns in CCA change some results?

Tags: correlation

When running CCA from [scikit learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA.html#sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA.fit), if the order is changed in the columns like (changing the order of the rows of both datasets together does not produce different results that I've seen -- not shown here),

```
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import CCA
import numpy as np

x15 = np.array([[5,3,6,7,3],[3,6,2,7,3],[3,4,6,4,4],[2,4,3,5,6]])
y14 = np.array([[3,4,2,5],[1,4,2,7],[2,3,5,6],[3,5,7,2]])
rng = np.random.default_rng()

x15_perm = np.random.permutation(x15.shape[1])
x15_perm_args = np.argsort(x15_perm)
x15 = x15[:, x15_perm]

y14_perm = np.random.permutation(y14.shape[1])
y14_perm_args = np.argsort(y14_perm)
y14 = y14[:, y14_perm]
```

Then fit and transform with CCA like,

```
ncomp = 3
ccaxy = CCA(n_components=ncomp) 
x15_c, y14_c = ccaxy.fit_transform(x15, y14)
```

These results change.

```
print(ccaxy.coef_)
print(x15_c)
print(y14_c)
```

And these, with retrieving the same ordering.

```
print(ccaxy.x_loadings_[x15_perm_args])
print(ccaxy.y_loadings_[y14_perm_args])
```

But this does not change.

```
comp_corre = [np.corrcoef(x15_c[:, i], y14_c[:, i])[1][0] for i in range(ncomp)]
print(comp_corre)
```

What is the explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

I realized it's due to the sample/feature ratio being low, when it's high, the results are fairly consistent. As can be seen with (rerunning everything below these).

```
x15 = np.sort(np.random.random((10000, 5)))
y14 = np.sort(np.random.random((10000, 4)))
```